# CI UNIX_TIMESTAMP where condition Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, date, where-clause

I have try to  build up a condition .but CI UNIX_TIMESTAMP does't Work There!!

```
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(insert_time) >', time() - 900);
```

**Within 15 minutes, the condition should be right. But the condition is not being right.**

Comment: time() returns the current time.So, this will return records inserted within last 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You could do the date arithemetics directly in the database:

```
$this->db->where('insert_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE');
```